# Best practice from removing accounts from Entitlement Processes

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

We have several internal accounts that had several entitlements mistakenly added to them. We do not want to have milestones associated with the cases under these accounts, but they now already have cases with milestones associated with them.

This prevents me from deleting the entitlements from the account, which means subsequent cases will have milestones.

What is the best practice for preventing future cases from having milestones on these internal accounts?

Should I try and fix all the associated cases and delete the entitlements from the account, or should I simply add some sort of close into the milestones saying that they won't get added to cases with internal accounts X, Y, & Z? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Milestones are linked through `Entitlement Process`. Since you have Accounts with Entitlement Records, so go to Entitlement Detail and update Entitlement Process to null.

Hence, **milestones will not get created anymore.**

[image: Entitlement Process]

You can also write a script to update Entitlement Details from developer console.

or, You can update mass data using dataloader.